# VueJS - VueX and flash messages

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I use **VueJS 2**, **VueX**, **NuxtJS** and **Vue-Snotify** ([artemsky/vue-snotify](https://github.com/artemsky/vue-snotify)) for flash notifications.

It may not be the correct use of VueX, but I'd like to **dispatch** the errors caught in a try/catch.

```
try {
    throw new Error('test')
} catch (error) {
    this.$store.dispatch('errorHandler', error)
}
```

Then the dispatch, with VueX should display the notifications with Snotify-View with a loop if there are several errors.

```
actions: {
    async errorHandler (error) {
        this.$snotify.error(error)
        // and if multiple errors, then while on error
    }
}
```

What do you think and how to recover the instance of $snotify in VueX?

Comment: I wouldn't use a vuex action if the code isn't going to affect the vuex state.

Comment: Ok, I see... But how I can make a component to trait all errors?

Comment: Add errors to an error stack (in Vuex), have a component on the page that interacts with the error stack and displays them using $snotify. Also thanks for the snort this morning with the name of that library :)

Comment: Thanks @Bert, but how I can get error stack from VueX? With setTimeout()? :)

Comment: You could get it from Vuex the same way you get anything from Vuex; using a getter. Your component would probably watch to call snotify when the stack changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Bad

I realize that the **app** instance is injected in the initialization of the **Vue** store. So, you can access through `this.app.$snotify` to the **Snotify** services where you want.

Also, another place at the **store** that receive the **Nuxt** context as the *second argument* is the `nuxtServerInit`[2]. Thus, you could **access** to the *service* using something like the next *snippet*.

```
actions: {
    nuxtServerInit ({ state }, { app }) {
        // Workaround
        state.Snotify = app.$snotify // inject the context in the store
    },
    // Then, you can called as you want
    // There is not necessity to prefix the method with async keyword
    errorHandler ({ state }, message) {
        state.Snotify.error(message)
    }
}
```

### Good

To my point of view the **store** doesn't have any responsibility to handler the presentation behavior of the data. Thus, the only goal of the **store**, in this case, is to pass the message between components to be displayed in other as a **flash message**, with **Snotify** in this particular case. So to conclude my appreciation of the statement, I think that actions only are responsible to change the **state** of the **store** as a **unique source of truth**, by [definition](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html).

You must use a **mutation** instead and store only the *Object*. Then, in your view or **HOC** (High Order Component) set up the presentation logic using **Snotify** where it's available. To support my answer I strong recommend [this](https://github.com/ahmed-dinar/vuex-flash#persist-flash-message) **library** due to it has a better **API** to communicate with **Vuex** and also it has a good presentation interface (UI/UX). Disclaimer: I'm not saying that this one is better than **Snotify**, each one was built to satisfy purpose slightly different, at least, as far as UX concept is concerned. Both are great and could be used either way to illustrate this use case.

---

I will change your second snippet for:

```
state: {
    flash: null
}
mutations: {
    // Just extract message from the context that you are set before
    SET_ERROR (state, { message, title = 'Something happens!' }) {
        state.flash = { 
            type: 'error',
            title, 
            message
        }
    },
    FLUSH_FLASH (state) {
        state.flash = null
    }
}
```

And also, I will add this on some view/layout/component/HOC (I used **SFC** way for its most common use)

```
<template>
    <vue-snotify />
    ...
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       // I use fetch because this is the lifecycle hook that executes 
       // immediately before page render is sure. And its purpose is to fill
       // the store before page render. But, to the best of my knowledge, 
       // this is the only place that you could use to trigger an immediately
       // executed function at the beginning of page render. However, also
       // you could use a middleware instead or "preferably use a wrapper 
       // component and get leverage of component lifecycle and use `mounted`" [4]
       fetch({ app, store }) {
           if (store.state.flash) {
               const { type, title, message: body } = store.state.flash
               const toast = app.$snotify[type](body, title)

               toast.on('destroyed', (t) => { store.commit('FLUSH_FLASH') })
           }
       },
       data: () => ({
           ...
       })
</script>
```

Maybe, the code above is not fully functional to you, but I suggest that you should test a similar approach and fit to your needs.

### EDIT

I want to point out another improvement to my answer, based on my last update related with **components lifecycle**. At the beginning, I actually want to put the message inside the component `mounted` method but then I thought that **Nuxt** pages have a **different** lifecycle until I see this [example](https://github.com/fishpercolator/open-all-hours/blob/master/components/Snackbar.vue) and realize that **Nuxt** still been **Vue** on the background. Thus, any page actually is also a **component** by [definition](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views) too. Then you could do a much semantic approach as well.

```
<template>
    <vue-snotify />
    ...
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       data: () => ({
           ...
       }),
       // Show the flash at the beginning when it's necessary
       mounted: {
           if (this.notification) {
               const { type, title, message: body } = this.notification
               const toast = this.$snotify[type](body, title)

               toast.on('destroyed', (t) => { this.$store.commit('FLUSH_FLASH') })
           }
       },
       computed: {
           notification () {
               return this.$store.state.flush
           }
       }
</script>
```

#### References

[1] https://zendev.com/2018/06/07/async-data-options-in-vue-nuxt.html

[2] https://twitter.com/krutiepatel/status/1000022559184764930

[3] https://github.com/artemsky/vue-snotify/blob/master/example/src/App/app.ts

[4] https://medium.com/@fishpercolator/implementing-a-global-snackbar-in-nuxt-js-vuetify-using-vuex-a92b78e5651b